# How to find a sum without hidden columns?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I want to find the sum of the columns except for the hidden columns. But "subtotal" function did not work for horizontal columns.

I want to make it this way:

| Column A | Column B | hidden Column C | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 5 | Cell1+Cell2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 | Cell3+Cell4 |

| Column A | Column B | hidden Column C | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 5 | =SUMIF($A$5:$C$5,">0",A3:C3) |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 | Cell 6 | =SUBTOTAL(109,A4,B4,C4) |
| =Cell("width",A1) | =Cell("width",B1) | =Cell("width",C1) |  |

In Excel, I used that the width of hidden cell was zero, but it didn't work in Google-Sheets. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
=SUM(IF(CELL("width",OFFSET(A1:D1,,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(A1:D1),0))),A1:D1))
```

[image: Before Collumn Hidden]

[image: After Collumn Hidden]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JBMdqnOXXjkZq0LJpGBfmdS-GsYL-t5_Bxxyu9kV2AQ/edit?usp=sharing thank you but it doesn't work.

Comment: This answer won't work in Google Sheets because in Excel hiding a column and setting its width to zero are equivalent operations (so using the 'width' argument to CELL will work here), whereas in Google Sheets they are not the same (i.e. a hidden column retains its width). My understanding is that detection of hidden columns is impossible in Google Sheets without the use of scripts. SUBTOTAL only works for hidden rows.

Comment: @imbeginner I just realized that you use it in Google Sheets, that's a formula I made for Excel, not Google Sheets